# Solve the equation $(a-b)^{ab} = a^b \cdot b^a$

Tags: number-theory

> Determine all pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that $a > b$ and $$(a-b)^{ab} = a^b \cdot b^a.$$

Let $a = d \alpha$ and $b = d \beta$ where $\gcd(\alpha,\beta) = 1$. Then the equation is equivalent to $d^{ab-a-b}(\alpha-\beta)^{ab} = \alpha^b \cdot \beta^b$. I then thought about taking cases based on whether $ab-a-b > 0$. How can we continue?

Comment: Just for the record, $(2,4)$ is one set of solutions, so they exist.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt you likely meant $(4,2)$ since $a>b$...

Comment: Taking the $ab$ root we get $a - b = a^{1/a}\cdot b^{1/b}$ and the right hand side is at most $e^{2/e} \sim 2.1$ so we must have $a-b = 2$ or $a-b=1$.

Comment: @Winther and with $a-b=1$, we need $a^bb^a=1$, which is absurd. While with $a-b=2$, both $a$ and $b$ must be powers of $2$, with difference $2$, so $a=4$, $b=2$.

Comment: What happened with the question about $a_1,...,a_{k+1}$, with $k$ the number of primes not greater than $n$ and such that each $a_i$ doesn't divide the product of the other $a_i$'s, that asked to show that at least one $a_i$ was larger than $n$?

Comment: @NinaSimone I undeleted it.

Answer (score 2):

$(a-b)^{ab} = a^b \cdot b^a$

$a-b = a^{1/a} \cdot b^{1/b}\leq e^{2/e}\approx 2,087$

=> $\,a=b+1\,$ or $\,a=b+2$

=> $1 = (b+1)^{1/(b+1)} \cdot b^{1/b}\,$ (no solution with positive integer $b$)

or $\,2 = (b+2)^{1/(b+2)} \cdot b^{1/b}$ with the only solution $b=2$